# Sum a returned result of Joint numbers

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've the below formula in my googlesheet

```
=ifna(Join("+",QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1EaHsRFMGf0UyI5QeJ5A6n-8a_9KkP2rVeRuOo05e608","Data!A2:AD"),"select Col9 where Col1 = '"&F963&"'",0)),"none")
```

That returns `2,300.00+50.00`

If I tried to `sum` them as `sum(ifna(Join("+",QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1EaHsRFMGf0UyI5QeJ5A6n-8a_9KkP2rVeRuOo05e608","Data!A2:AD"),"select Col9 where Col1 = '"&F963&"'",0)),"none"))` The output I'm getting is `0`

What modification is required to be able to get the total sum in the returned result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`=IFERROR(SUM(SPLIT(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1EaHsRFMGf0UyI5QeJ5A6n-8a_9KkP2rVeRuOo05e608", "Data!A2:AD"),"select Col9 where Col1 = '"&F963&"'",0),"+")),"none")`